# SPARK - import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset not working (unresolved symbol Dataset)

Tags: apache-spark

> My maven dependencies.
>   SPARK - import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset not working (unresolved
>   symbol Dataset)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: DataSet API was added in Spark 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using an older version i.e 1.4.0. Use any higher version such as 2.1.1 and it should work.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Nephilim, Resolved the issue. I used the above dependencies.